# Date from Model does not display in TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using `Html.TextBoxFor` to set and display dates from Model.  They work fine when setting the values, however when I retrieve values from the database, they do not display the dates:

[image]
Here is my HTML:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.effectiveDate, "Select Effective Date", new {@class="date form-control", id= "reqEffectiveDate" }`)

If I switch to `@Html.EditorFor`, the dates display, but the element no longer displays like the other "form-control" elements on the page, and clicking in the box no longer displays the datepicker:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EditorFor` doesn't apply any CSS classes by default, unless you have defined a custom editor template.

You need to pass a collection of HTML attributes to the editor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.effectiveDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "date form-control", id = "reqEffectiveDate" } })
```